# Jquery noconflict issue

Tags: jquery

I have these these 2 js codes and cant merge them, so that they work properly.

Maybe you guys can help me out:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $('#ex1').zoom();
    $('#ex2').zoom({ on:'grab' });
    $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });          
    $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
});      

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

I tried the following, which didnt work:

```
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() 
    $('#ex1').zoom();
    $('#ex2').zoom({ on:'grab' });
    $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });          
    $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
});   
</script>
```

ok this seems to work, it just didnt work offline. Thank you !

Comment: What is the error you get with this? also it seems you have too many closing brackets and missing opening bracket for doc ready

Comment: 1. Why do you think you need `noConflict`? 2. It looks like you have an extra `});` at the end.

Comment: the scripts just dont work - one is a zooming plugin, the other one fancy box.

Comment: it didnt work without noconflict, so I tried this solution.

Comment: The formatted code reveals an obvious syntax error.

Comment: noConflict is only used if, say, you were using Dojo and jQuery on the same page, so as not to conflict with the other libraries. jQuery plugins don't require it.

Comment: First of all, there isn't a *need* to merge them together. Secondly, as mentioned above, you have an extra closing `});`

Comment: ok , tried it without noconflict and removed the closing bracktes, one script still doesnt work

Comment: here is the site: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10626022/echse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have all the brackets mixed up, use the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ex1').zoom();
  $('#ex2').zoom({ on:'grab' });
  $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });          
  $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

You had missing open { for doc ready and extra closing brackets for doc ready

Comment: ok this seems to work, it just didnt work offline. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. why not use just one document ready hook? :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ex1').zoom();
  $('#ex2').zoom({ on:'grab' });
  $('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });          
  $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});      
</script>
```

Comment: that's not my fault.. are you using multiple plugins for same element?

Comment: I ve uploaded the site, maybe u can spot the issue:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10626022/echse.html

Comment: what do you mean ? can u check it like that ?

Comment: ok this seems to work, it just didnt work offline. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

I put this is my master page of my site

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function(){ 
    j('#ex1').zoom();
    j('#ex2').zoom({ on:'grab' });
    j('#ex3').zoom({ on:'click' });          
    j('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
    j('.fancybox').fancybox();
});     
</script>
```

Comment: same as above, zoom plugin working - fancy box isnt.